# Color in ggplot, continuous value supplied to discrete scale

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting points over a heat map produced in ggplot2. `delta` is a data frame containing points to be plotted over heat map. The variable `plt` stores the ggplot image.

The heat map is produced by the code from this link (could not post here because of text limitation). Also, the reproducible code for all required data frames is in the link.

https://justpaste.it/65iu7

Now to superimpose points over the heat map, I used the code below:

```
plt0 <- plt + geom_point(data = delta, aes(x = dP/100, y = dT, z = NULL,  color = rcp, shape = future))
plt0
```

It gives error:

> Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale.

If I remove `color = future` from the above code, it works. But I need to have color coded points as this code produces:

```
ggplot()+geom_point(data = delta, aes(x = dP/100, y = dT, z = NULL, color = rcp, shape = future))
```

What is producing this error and how can I solve it?

Comment: It works perfectly fine for me, without any error.

Comment: Please provide the dataframe with `dput(delta)`. So that we can test.

Comment: Ah ok it is in the link... well, not a usual practice here.

Comment: @rar can you please show the result ? for me it produced "Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale."

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent all those dput() results exceeded the character limitation of stackoverflow and I had to use an external link.

Comment: @anup Ok. But in such a situation you can post just an extract of the data, a sufficient one to reproduce.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent ok thank you for the information. btw, do you have any solution to my problem ?

Comment: @anup This works if you start like this: `plt <- ggplot() + geom_tile(data=new.data, aes(x = hh/100, y = tt, z = floor(W), fill=W)) + ......`. But there's a problem: `z` is ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Is it ok like this?

```
plt <- ggplot() + geom_tile(data=new.data, aes(x = hh/100, y = tt, fill=W)) +
  geom_contour(data=new.data, bins = 10, 
               aes(x = hh/100, y = tt, #color = ..level.., 
                   z = floor(W)), 
               show.legend = FALSE) +
  ylab("Change in temperature in degree Celsius") +
  xlab("percentage change in precipitation") +
  scale_fill_gradientn(name = "W (in m3/year)",
                       values = scales::rescale(quantile(new.data$W)),
                       limits = c(min(new.data$W),max(new.data$W)),
                       breaks = seq(round(min(new.data$W)/1000000)*1000000,
                                    round(max(new.data$W)/1000000)*1000000,
                                    (round(max(new.data$W)/1000000)*1000000-round(min(new.data$W)/1000000)*1000000)/3),
                       colors = rainbow(7), guide = "colorbar") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(-0.3,0.3, 0.1), label = scales::percent) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(-1, 6, 1)) +
  ggtitle("Variation of average annual sediment production with \n temperature and precipitation")+
  guides(fill = guide_colorbar(barwidth = 0.5, barheight = 10))

plt

plt + 
  geom_point(data = delta, aes(x = dP/100, y = dT,
                               color = rcp, shape = future))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I did not change the code except for the first line. Instead of :

```
plt<-ggplot(new.data, aes(x = hh/100, y = tt, z = floor(W))) + geom_tile(aes(fill = W)) + ...
```

Used

```
plt<-ggplot()+ geom_tile(new.data, aes(x = hh/100, y = tt, fill = W)) + ...
```

This is to ascertain that we call empty `ggplot` and then add `geom_tile` with `new.data` and since the `ggplot` has not been assigned any data as default, we can later on add delta for `geom_point`. The output is as follows:
[image]